# How to count the number of words in a sentence, ignoring numbers, punctuation and whitespace?

Tags: python, list, text, counter, text-processing

How would I go about counting the words in a sentence? I'm using Python.

For example, I might have the string:

```
string = "I     am having  a   very  nice  23!@$      day. "
```

That would be 7 words. I'm having trouble with the random amount of spaces after/before each word as well as when numbers or symbols are involved.

Comment: To accomodate the numbers, you can change the regex. `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]` Now, you need to define what your use case is. What happens to `I am fine2` ? Would it be 2 words or 3 ?

Comment: You needed to explicitly add *"ignoring numbers, punctuation and whitespace"* since that's part of the task.

Comment: FYI some punctuation symbols may merit separate consideration. Otherwise, *"carry-on luggage"* becomes three words, as does *"U.S.A."* So answers may want to parameterize what punctuation is allowed, rather than blanket regex like `\S+`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without any arguments splits on runs of whitespace characters:

```
>>> s = 'I am having a very nice day.'
>>> 
>>> len(s.split())
7
```

From the linked documentation:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: One (very minor) disadvantage of this would be that you could have punctuation groups counted as words.  For example, in `'I am having a very nice day -- or at least I was.'`, you'd get `--` counted as a word.  `isalnum` might help, I guess, depending on the OP's definition of "word".

Comment: This seems to be faster than regex

Comment: Of course it's faster, but it's also much more limited.

Comment: Nope, counts punctuation: `'apple & orange'.split()` gives `['apple', '&', 'orange']`

Answer (score 66):

You can use [`regex.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
line = " I am having a very nice day."
count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', line))
print (count)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd usually avoid regex if I can, but this seems like a pretty good use case.

Comment: +1 for using `re`, it is truly better than `[i for i in string.split() if i.isalnum()]`

Comment: I'd rather rely on counting `\S+` to handle things like decimal numbers in `"It's 2.5 times faster"`

Comment: If line is `'inter-process communication'`, it will count 3 words

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Just curious. Why do you try to avoid using regex ?

Comment: @Catbuilts The reason is simple. Regex can often get complicated fast, and depending on what language or implementation you use, they may have different effects. There's nothing wrong with using them, I just don't quite like them as much.

Answer (score 7):

```
s = "I     am having  a   very  nice  23!@$      day. "
sum([i.strip(string.punctuation).isalpha() for i in s.split()])
```

The statement above will go through each chunk of text and remove punctuations before verifying if the chunk is really string of alphabets.

Comment: 1. Using `i` as a nonindex variable is really misleading; 2. you don't need to create a list, it's just wasting memory. Suggestion: `sum(word.strip(string.punctuation).isalpha() for word in s.split())`

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple word counter using regex. The script includes a loop which you can terminate it when you're done.

```
#word counter using regex
import re
while True:
    string =raw_input("Enter the string: ")
    count = len(re.findall("[a-zA-Z_]+", string))
    if line == "Done": #command to terminate the loop
        break
    print (count)
print ("Terminated")
```

Comment: Change `raw_input` to `input` in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Ok here is my version of doing this. I noticed that you want your output to be `7`, which means you dont want to count special characters and numbers. So here is regex pattern:

```
re.findall("[a-zA-Z_]+", string)
```

Where `[a-zA-Z_]` means it will match **any** character beetwen `a-z` (lowercase) and `A-Z` (upper case).

---

About spaces. If you want to remove all extra spaces, just do:

```
string = string.rstrip().lstrip() # Remove all extra spaces at the start and at the end of the string
while "  " in string: # While  there are 2 spaces beetwen words in our string...
    string = string.replace("  ", " ") # ... replace them by one space!
```

Comment: Doesn't work for non-english characters like ćęźńśü

Answer (score 4):

```
def wordCount(mystring):
    tempcount = 0
    count = 1

    try:
        for character in mystring:
            if character == " ":
                tempcount +=1
                if tempcount ==1:
                    count +=1

                else:
                    tempcount +=1
             else:
                 tempcount=0

         return count

     except Exception:
         error = "Not a string"
         return error

mystring = "I   am having   a    very nice 23!@$      day."

print(wordCount(mystring))
```

output is 8

Comment: Was looking for a solution without use of builtin functions like strip, split, etc.
But this code fails with leading/trailing whitespaces.

Comment: This is the best answer since it does not use any standard library.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a simple loop to count the occurrences of number of spaces!?

```py
txt = "Just an example here move along" 
count = 1
for i in txt:
    if i == " ":
       count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: here is another approach print(input().count(' ') + 1)

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string 

sentence = "I     am having  a   very  nice  23!@$      day. "
# Remove all punctuations
sentence = sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
# Remove all numbers"
sentence = ''.join([word for word in sentence if not word.isdigit()])
count = 0;
for index in range(len(sentence)-1) :
    if sentence[index+1].isspace() and not sentence[index].isspace():
        count += 1 
print(count)
```