# How to get particular file word count from AWS S3 storage using lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My scenario, I am trying to get particular AWS S3 stored text `file` `word count` and its `language detection` using `AWS lambda` python code. Here, below code I am trying. It is providing line count but I don't know how to get word count and language detection. Please provide some idea for get file word count and language detection.

I tried for line count

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # create the s3 resource
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    # get the file object
    obj = s3.Object('bucket name', 'sample.txt')

    # read the file contents in memory
    file_contents = obj.get()["Body"].read()

    # print the occurrences of the new line character to get the number of lines
    # print file_contents.count('\n')
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'Line Count': file_contents.count('\n')
    }
```

> Current Response:
>       {
>         "Line Count": 48,
>       }
>
> Expected Response:
>       {
>         "Line Count": 48,
>         "Word Count": : ?, // Here I want to show word count 
>         "Language": ? // Here language name
>       }

Comment: You say it's not working, could you perhaps give more details about what's not working? Could you also provide a sample file and what you expect to get back from that file?

Comment: Hi @NickChapman I updated my question could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of words you can try any of the things listed here: [How to count the number of words in a sentence, ignoring numbers, punctuation and whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410018/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-sentence-ignoring-numbers-punctuation-an)

To detect the language you can try one of the things listed here: [NLTK and language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182268/nltk-and-language-detection)

Unfortunately, your question is rather broad. Additionally, the task of detecting a text's language is rather difficult to get right. Getting the word count is easy but depends a lot on what you are going to define a word as.