# python how to count words in a list element

Tags: python, list, counting

below code returns a list:

```
[['We test robots'], ['Give us a try'], [' ']]
```

now I need to count words in each element, 
how could I achieve this in Python without importing any packages. In the above I should get 3,4 and 1 for three list elements. 
thanks

```
import re
S ="We test robots.Give us a try? "

splitted = [l.split(',') for l in (re.split('\.|\!|\?',S)) if l]

print (splitted)
```

Comment: if you need to count words in each element of the list then shouldn't the output be 3,4,0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of words in a sentence, ignoring numbers, punctuation and whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410018/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-sentence-ignoring-numbers-punctuation-an)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***for calculating words in each elements***

```
import re
S ="We test robots.Give us a try? "

splitted = [l.split(',') for l in (re.split('\.|\!|\?',S)) if l]

item =[]
for i in splitted:
    item.append(len(i[0].split()))

print(item)
```

**output will be**  [3,4,0]

Comment: love this, thanks, easy to read and to understand for beginners like me :)

Comment: This imports the regex library though, which is what OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this, here's two:

```
# using map
list(map(lambda x: len(x[0].split()) if len(x[0]) > 1 else 1, l))

[3, 4, 1]

# using list comprehension
[len(x[0].split()) if len(x[0]) > 1 else 1 for x in l]

[3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: can't your self condition just be 1, as in `[len(i[0].split()) if len(i[0]) > 1 else 1 for i in lst]`

Comment: umm I think so, we can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do something like:

```
import re
S ="We test robots.Give us a try? "

splitted = [l.split(',') for l in (re.split('\.|\!|\?',S)) if l]

print(splitted)

for sentence in splitted:
    count = len(sentence[0].split())
    if not count and sentence[0]:
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

Would prints:

```
[['We test robots'], ['Give us a try'], [' ']]
3
4
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your input elements are lists, and all delimiters are spaces, then you can do this without importing anything:

```
input = [['We test robots'], ['Give us a try'], [' ']]
output = []

for item in input:
   output.append(len(item[0].split()))

print(output)  # [3, 4, 0]
```

If you want an empty item to print 1 instead of 0, just check if the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just practicing...

```
def word_counter(passlist):
    do_count = lambda x: len(x.split())
    result=[]

    for elem in passlist:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            result += [word_counter(elem)]
        elif isinstance(elem, str):
            result += [do_count(elem)]

    return result

print(word_counter([['We test robots'], ['Give us a try'], [' ']]))
# output: [[3], [4], [0]]

print(word_counter(['First of all', ['One more test'], [['Trying different list levels'], [' ']], 'Something more here']))
# output: [3, [3], [[4], [0]], 3]
```